# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$.

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> Let $a_n$ denote the exponent of $2$ in the numerator of $\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{2^i}{i}$ when written in the lowest form. For example, $a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=2.$ Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$.

> Source: problem 11 from [this problem set](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ex46wang/Weekly/2022/A5.pdf).

One could try to compute the first few values of the expression, but it's very unlikely that there's a pattern in the terms of the sequence. We obviously just need to find an unbounded subsequence (e.g. a strictly increasing subsequence). There probably isn't an explicit formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{2^i}i$. The denominator of the fraction would clearly divide $n!,$ and by Legendre's formula, $v_p(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lfloor n/p^i\rfloor$ for any prime number p and positive integer n. We clearly have that $\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{2^i}i = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i\cdot n!/i}{n!}$. Also, there are several basic properties of $v_p(n)$ that could be useful.Let $K_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{2^i}i$ for all n. Then $K_1 = 2, K_2 = 1/2(2\cdot 2 + 4\cdot 1) = 4.$ The hint to the problem says that the series equals $-\log(1-x)$ for $x=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, though how does this even make sense when $-\log(1-x)$ isn't defined for $x<0$?

Comment: FYI, an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cdfrac%7B2%5Ei%7D%7Bi%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7Da_n%3D%5Cinfty%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aexponent%2C%20OR%20content%3Alowest%20form&p=1) lists quite a few questions here which deal with $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2^i}{i}$ in some manner. Regarding specifically about "$-\log(1-x)$ for $x=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$", this [answer](/a/4032225) provides an explanation. Also, other fairly closely related questions, which might be of some use, are ...

Comment: (cont.) [How can $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$ be divisible by $2^M$?](/q/1959303), [How prove this $x_{2^n}\ge 2^n-n+1$](/q/659579), [How to estimate the highest power of 2 in the partial sum of 2-adic $\log(-1)$ ( $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{i}$)?](/q/4145192), etc. In addition, other related questions include [Combinatorial proof that 2-adic sum $\sum_{n>0} 2^n/n=0$](/q/1990667), [Asymptotic behavior of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k}{k}$](/q/888354), [A limit involving $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2^k}{k}$](/q/2345610), etc.